# php form and onsubmit javascript function call

Tags: php, javascript

I've created a form with html being echoed in PHP and am trying to call a Javascript function in the same form. I've copied and pasted the js part which I have put in my head tags at the top of the php file.

```
<script>
    function validate(){
        alert("You need to enter the date in format dd-mm-yyyy");
    }
</script>
```

Further on I have this at the start of the form

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"index.php\" onsubmit=\"validate()\">
        <br>
        <span>Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"$name\"></span>"
```

Is it possible to call javascript from php in the same document? 
Cheers

Comment: calling JavaScript function inside PHP (in server side) is like to call undefined function, but if you mean calling the function in client side, then yes you can

Comment: Is better if you do an ajax control

Comment: @Akam The thing is I use PHP to create a form if a button is clicked because it processes using the same file.

Answer (score 1):

you have to try this inside php code ..

```
       echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        function validate(){
         alert('You need to enter the date in format dd-mm-yyyy');
                        }
     </script>";
```

Hope it use-full fro you..

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument, you tried moving your script to the bottom of your page?

```
echo ... validate()
...
<script>function validate()</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your function available when it is executed.

```
window.onload = function() {
    function validate(){
        alert("You need to enter the date in format dd-mm-yyyy");
    }
};
```